# css navbar responsive padding issue

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar every thing looks great until it goes responsive. the bottom drop down has a 5 px gap all the way around it.

https://jsfiddle.net/nc2hamed/5/

i have tried adding and removing padding on the

```
.expand {
    max-height: 40em;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top gap is because your .menu has big padding-top.
The left and right gaps are there because your .wrap has width: 95% (not 100%).
So this code will fix both issues:

```
.navbar {
    width: 105%;
    margin: 0 -2.5%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .navbar {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar .menu {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove some `padding-top` on `.navbar .menu` and set the `max-width` to `100%`

```
@media(your_media_query) {
   .navbar .menu {
     padding-top: 25px;
   }

   .wrap {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: it does nothing for the width

Comment: @Case you have a `max-width` on the wrapper that is making it look like it's padding. Edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your `.navbar .menu` element. You need to set the `padding-top` to `0px` unless your screen height is not mobile.